# Does process ID of VM change?

Tags: ubuntu, qemu, kvm, libvirt

What happens to the process ID of a VM on the host, if the VM is shutdown, reboot or killed? Does the process ID of the VM remains same?

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question. You may be able to get help on [su].

Comment: Sure I'll put out the question in Super user

Answer (score 0):

No, when we stop and start the VM again - the process ID changes.